# Pyserial reading incoming informations with unusual answer

Tags: python, serial-port, decode, communication

I'm trying to communicate with a UIRobot UIM 2502 modul. I can ask some things like bitrate and so on. When i'm trying to get the actual motor position, the answer is not a normal hex code.

I can use the program StepEva to get the current position and to move the stepper. So i moved the stepper with StepEva and asked the position by python. The results are as comments in the code.

```
from serial import Serial
ser = Serial(port='COM7', baudrate=38400, timeout=1, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1)
commando = 'POS;'
ser.write(commando.encode())
response=ser.readline()
print(response)
# responses:
# b'\xcc\x05\xb0\x00\x00\x00\x009\xff'            StepEva position:     57
# b'\xcc\x05\xb0\x00\x00\x00\x01T\xff'            StepEva position:    212
# b'\xcc\x05\xb0\x0f\x7f\x7f<\x13\xff             StepEva position:  -8685
```

I dont know how to convert this hexcode. The manual says the 5 bytes after the b0 byte descibe the position.
POS response from the manual:
CC  [Controller ID]  B0  [P0]  [P1]  [P2]  [P3]  [P4]  FF

Comment: B0  >>  The message ID of
current position [P0] ~ [P4] >>  Received data 0 ~ 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to "Page 18 Figure5-1: Conversion from three 7bits message data to a 16bits data" of [User Manual UIM2502](http://www.uirobot.com/uploads/2017/08/081532318235.pdf) and "Page 62 Figure12-2: Conversion from five 7bits message data to a 32bits data" of [User Manual UIM242XX Series](http://www.uirobot.com/uploads/2017/07/131441078237.pdf), each byte contains 7-bit value, which you can expect to concatenate in big-endian form into 32-bit integer.

The message for your question is not included in the document, but according to the question, the numbers will be 32-bit signed integers.
As a Python program, it will be as follows.

```
def getPosition(response):
    position = 0
    for i in range(3,8):
        position <<= 7
        position += response[i]

    if position > 0x7FFFFFFF:
        position -= 0x100000000

    return position
```

For example, it can be used as follows.

```
print(getPosition(b'\xcc\x05\xb0\x00\x00\x00\x009\xff')) # result is 57
print(getPosition(b'\xcc\x05\xb0\x00\x00\x00\x01T\xff')) #           212
print(getPosition(b'\xcc\x05\xb0\x0f\x7f\x7f<\x13\xff')) #           -8685

response=ser.readline()
position=getPosition(response)
print(position)
```

By the way, I have not looked at the contents, but when I search, there is such a package, so there may be functions that can be used in various ways.
[python-can](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html)

Comment: I've spend a lot of time to get this work and now your answer helps me a lot.

Comment: Just to understand: What does  'position <<= 7' means and what's the reason of the if loop?

Comment: The 'position << = 7' of the **for** loop is to shift the result added at the previous cycle of the loop by 7 bits in order to concatenate each byte of data by 7 bits. This is processing according to the figure of the document. The **if** after the loop is to check the value of the sign bit and convert it to a negative number.

Comment: One more question:
When i am asking for speed and the sign is negative, there is a big number decoded.
b'\xcc\t\xb2\x7fx\x18\xff' shold equal -1000 but i get 2096152
What could be the problem?

Comment: Isn't that the value of 16bit is notified instead of the value of 32bit? The third byte, \xb2, seems to represent the data format. Maybe \xb0 is a 32bit value and \xb2 is a 16bit value? Please try to find such a difference from the specifications.

Comment: @kunif , I came across the internet just to ask you to take a look on my question please 

[link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/660813/unable-to-clear-faults-on-monoblock-via-rs232-command-need-help-decoding-serial)